# One repository, two CodeBuild projects, only one webhook works

Tags: webhooks, aws-codebuild

We have two CodeBuild projects in order to test frontend and backend parts of our app that reside in one repository. Two webhooks are set up accordingly, but when PR is initiated only one project kicks in and Github shows '1 check pending'. Once I managed to launch the second build somehow, probably by stopping first build, but I'm not sure how now, can't reproduce it anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for using CodeBuild. Can you take a look at your webhook responses in your Repository Settings -> Webhooks -> Recent deliveries? It should have some detailed information about why your webhook didn't trigger builds.

Comment: Thanks for response, this issue was probably caused by maximum concurrent build limit. Once it was increased by support, it was gone. Though it was kinda obscure and would be much better if AWS showed something on its side.